# Why does the error "asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError" occur?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, aiohttp

Before yesterday the program completed without errors, but today after each program termination this error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\PycharmProjects\MY-TELEGRAM-BOT\BOT\MAIN.py", line 437, in main
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\PycharmProjects\MY-TELEGRAM-BOT\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 543, in start_polling
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 418, in wait
    return await _wait(fs, timeout, return_when, loop)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 525, in _wait
    await waiter
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\PycharmProjects\MY-TELEGRAM-BOT\BOT\MAIN.py", line 442, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ALEXE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 123, in run
    raise KeyboardInterrupt()
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

I don't end the program with the ctrl+c key combination, I just press the stop button.

Maybe I'm terminating the session incorrectly? I just don't know why this error occurred, because it didn't exist before.

```
async def main():
    try:
        await client.start()
        await client.connect()
        await dp.start_polling(bot)
    finally:
        await client.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I would be grateful for any help or advice.

Comment: What does the stop button do if not send a keyboard interrupt? I have no idea how your start_polling() works, but if you want to exit cleanly, then you need to add code to do that. For example, by catching the exception or using something like `loop.add_signal_handler()` (something usually handled for you when using a web framework like aiohttp).

Answer (score 0):

you just need to catch **CancelledError** in **main()** to terminate the bot without errors. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-cancellation).